# Excel VBA Javascript Export

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, export

I am attempting to export a report from a SQL Server Reporting Services site, and am using Excel 07 and IE7. I have the code all the way up

```
 Sub TestIE()
 Dim IE2 As Object
 Set IE2 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE2.Visible = True
 IE2.navigate "http://www.site.com"
 Application.StatusBar = "Accessing the report"
 Do While IE2.Busy
 Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
 Loop

 Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy: Set CurrentWindow = IE2.document.parentWindow
 Call CurrentWindow.execScript("$find('ctl31')")
 End Sub
```

The site that I'm pulling the data from shows this as it's Javascript.

```
 <div class="NormalButton">
 <a class="ActiveLink" onclick="$find('ctl31').exportReport('EXCEL');" 
 href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding:3px 8px 3px 8px;display:block;
 white-space:nowrap;text-decoration:none;">Excel</a>
```

When I run my macro, this code does nothing.

```
 Call CurrentWindow.execScript("$find('ctl31')")
```

But when I use the below code from the site Source, I get the Run Time Error 80020101.

```
 Call CurrentWindow.execScript("$find('ctl31').exportReport('EXCEL');")
```

Can anyone recommend what I can do to pull this data?

Comment: What happens if you call the `click` event on the link?

Comment: I get a Run-time Error '91'. Object variable with block variable not set. I'm using: IE.Document.all("$find('ctl31').exportReport('EXCEL');").Click

Comment: That's not going to work. You need to find the `a` element and click on that. Maybe try `getElementsByTagName("a")` and check the returned collection for an element with `innerText`="Excel"

Comment: Ok, will do first thing! Thanks for the input!

Comment: Ok, so I got pretty far, to the point where I'm able to use this to find identifiers. ` Set Document = Browser.Document Set Elements = Document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl06_ctl04_ctl00_Menu").getElementsByTagName("a") For Each Element In Elements 'set objElement as the Element with the InnerText of "Excel" so that I can say objElement.Click Next Element` Now, I need to figure a way to set the specific Element so that I can click on it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I got the basics done on this file. I opened a new questions specificly for VBA's For Each procedure, but the main Javascript issue here is closed.